# Index out of bound Exception... and sorting is wrong, please check below code, what is the problem?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, sorting

Index out of bound Exception... and sorting is wrong, please check below code, what is the problem ??

it takes string and an integer as input, it computes all the substrings of length k then sees which substring is lexicographically first and last and sorts it inside collection array and returns lexicographically smallest as smallest and largest as largest

```
public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {


    String smallest = "";
    String largest = "";
    String[] collections = new String[s.length()-k];
    for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-k-1; i++) {

        // if(i==(s.length()-k)){
        //   collections[i] = s.substring(i,i+k-1);  
        // }
        collections[i] = s.substring(i,i+k);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<collections.length;i++){
    System.out.print(collections[i]+" "); 
    }
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i=0;i<collections.length-1;i++){
        for(int q=1;q<collections.length;q++){
            if(collections[i].compareTo(collections[q])<0){
                String temp = collections[i]; 
                collections[i]=collections[q];
                collections[q]=temp; 
            }
        }
    }
    smallest = collections[0]; 
    largest = collections[collections.length-1];
    for(int i=0; i<collections.length;i++){
    System.out.print(collections[i]+" "); 
    }
    System.out.println("");
    // s.substring(0,3) , s.substring(3,6) , substring(i,i+k)
    return smallest + "\n" + largest;
}
```

Comment: First thing to do would be to determine what line the exception is occurring on.  You should find that information in the stack trace for the exception.  Once you know that, then you can step through the code in the debugger, or you can use System.out.println statements to print variable values.  I suspect the line s.substring(i,i+k); could be the source of your problem, but you'll have to use the steps I just mentioned to determine that.

Comment: I've printed the elemets inside in collections array you can see using for loops

Comment: Problem is when i = s.length()-k in the first for loop then  error occurs but that should be covered using loop or else one last substring will be missed in collections array

Comment: You aren't printing variable values in the first loop, which could likely be the source of your problem.  Again, please look at the stack trace which will tell you the exact line number where the exception is occurring.

Comment: See second loop after allocation in collection array, there values are printed

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't told us what the code is meant to do, or which inputs are failing. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to be *much* clearer. I'd also suggest using much more whitespace within the code and proper indentation. It's very hard to read while it's so dense.

Comment: Ok it takes string and an integer as input, it computes all the substrings of length k then sees which substring is lexicographically first and last and sorts it inside collection array and returns lexicographically smallest as smallest and largest as largest

Answer (score 0):

1. Your array size is to small. For Example: if your string is 6 characters long and the substring length k would be 5, your array should fit 2 strings inside.
2. To compensate for the too small array you reduced the loop also by 1, effectively ignoring the last substring.
3. Whatever sorting-algorithm you tried to implement made little sense. If you want to implement the sorting yourself, have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/). If you're fine with using java sorting the array for you, use Collections.sort() which takes the array in form of a list.

Additional Note: uppercase characters have a lower index

The fixed code would look like this:

```
public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {

    String smallest = "";
    String largest = "";

    //1. create an array with the length of possible substrings
    String[] collections = new String[s.length() - k + 1];
    
    //2. fill the array with these substrings
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - k; i++) {
        collections[i] = s.substring(i, i + k);
    }

    //print all substrings in original order
    for (int i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(collections[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    //3. sort the array
    Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(collections));

    smallest = collections[0];
    largest = collections[collections.length - 1];

    //print in sorted order
    for (int i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(collections[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    return smallest + "\n" + largest;
}
```

If you're asking a question you should also provide context and examples for your inputs, the expected outputs and the whole Stacktrace if there is one. That way other people don't need to reproduce the error themselves to help you. Also formatting and commenting your code helps a lot.